# Batch file to read a txt with special characters and replace a word in it

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file that reads a txt file "ayylmao.txt" and find a specific word "hello" and replaces it with "xello".

The thing is that the "ayylmao.txt" contains specific characters.

Ayylmao.txt looks something like this:

```
‹‹R‹Ę‹/M‹;Ču‹č˙˙˙‹‹@‰‹‹@CëC;Đu‹čq˙˙˙‹‹@C‹D$‰;7u®‹Ó‹Ćčúţ˙˙„Ŕu3Ŕ‰YZ]_^[ĂŤ@             SVWUÄđ‰$‹ô‹‰D$‹
‹‹@;Č‚†   ‹Ř‹>_‹ůz;ßrv;Ču!‹B‹A‹B‹)B‹x uV‹čđţ˙˙ëM‹Ř‹>_‹ůz;ßu
‹B‹)Bë3‹Z‰\$‹>‹‹.}+ű‰|$+Č‹‰HŤT$‹čMţ˙˙„Ŕu3 hello Ŕë°ë‹‹ ‰‹;D$…Y˙˙˙3ŔÄ]_^[ĂSVW‹Ú‹đţ   }ľ   ëĆ˙˙  ć  ˙˙‰sjh    Vj
```

You can see the "hello" word in the last line. I want the batch to go to the process and give me a ayylmao1.txt that looks like this:

```
‹‹R‹Ę‹/M‹;Ču‹č˙˙˙‹‹@‰‹‹@CëC;Đu‹čq˙˙˙‹‹@C‹D$‰;7u®‹Ó‹Ćčúţ˙˙„Ŕu3Ŕ‰YZ]_^[ĂŤ@             SVWUÄđ‰$‹ô‹‰D$‹
‹‹@;Č‚†   ‹Ř‹>_‹ůz;ßrv;Ču!‹B‹A‹B‹)B‹x uV‹čđţ˙˙ëM‹Ř‹>_‹ůz;ßu
‹B‹)Bë3‹Z‰\$‹>‹‹.}+ű‰|$+Č‹‰HŤT$‹čMţ˙˙„Ŕu3 xello Ŕë°ë‹‹ ‰‹;D$…Y˙˙˙3ŔÄ]_^[ĂSVW‹Ú‹đţ   }ľ   ëĆ˙˙  ć  ˙˙‰sjh    Vj
```

You can see that "hello" is now "xello".

I found this batch file that replaces a word from a text file:

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

This code works for files that don't have specific characters very good if use it like this:

```
code.bat "hello" "xello" "ayylmao.txt">"ayylmao1.txt"
```

This code only types in ayylmao1.txt few special characters but replaces hello. I want all the special characters typed in there.

I made it like this:

```
chcp 1252
code.bat "hello" "xello" "ayylmao.txt">"ayylmao1.txt"
```

But it didn't work. It worked just like the first code.

If there is a way in PowerShell to do this I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there looks like a binary file, not a text file, despite the extension. Batch is no good for editing binary files. In PowerShell it's doable, but you need to resort to working with the data bytes instead of simple text.

This is a basic example that will find the first occurrence of the string "hello" in your file and replace it with "xhello":

```
$f = 'C:\path\to\ayylmao.txt'

$stext   = 'hello'
$rtext   = [char[]]'xhello'

$len    = $stext.Length
$offset = $len - 1

$data = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($f)

# find first occurrence of $stext in byte array
for ($i=0; $i -lt $data.Count - $offset; $i++) {
  $slice = $data[$i..($i+$offset)]
  if (-join [char[]]$slice -eq $stext) { break }
}

# Once you know the beginning ($i) and length ($len) of the array slice
# containing $stext you can "cut up" $data and concatenate the slices before
# and after $stext to the byte sequence you want to insert ($rtext):
#
#      |<--   $stext    -->|
# [...]['h','e','l','l','o'][...]  <-- $data
#    ^   ^               ^   ^
#    |   |               |   |
#    |   $i              |   $i+$len
#    $i-1                $i+$offset (== $i+$len-1)
#
$rdata = $data[0..($i-1)] + [byte[]]$rtext + $data[($i+$len)..($data.Count-1)]

[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($f, $rdata)
```

You'll need to adjust this code if you want the replacement to work differently (replace other occurrences as well, replace a different occurrence, …).

Answer (score 1):

> But it didn't work. It worked just like the first code. Help ?

This batch code is coming from this [site](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#Batch.FindAndReplace) and there is a link to [discussion](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=2600&highlight=#2600) why it doesn't work with special characters.

Comment: This does not work with binary files like the OP obviously has.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You are right. I modified encoding type to Byte instead of UTF8.

Comment: With the encoding set to Byte you get a byte array which doesn't have a method `Replace()`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, you are right again. lol. Thanks for advising that. I removed my PowerShell answer. I upvoted yours so it is showing as the top answer. I left my answer with links to the website regarding the first question why batch file doesnt work.

Comment: You may want to summarize the discussion fron that forum, so your answer will still be valid (and helpful) if the remote thread disappears for some reason.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, that would be a good idea. I will go over that discussion why it doesnt work and I will try to summarize this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the PowerShell *replace* command can replace the string and keep the special characters.  To call it from within your batch script, use the following line

```
powershell -command "(get-content Ayylmao.txt) -replace 'hello','xello' | set-content Ayylmao.txt"
```

If you want to enter your parameters from the command line, then the line would be

```
powershell -command "(get-content %3) -replace '%1','%2' | set-content %4"
```

And if you want to use variables defined in the batch script, it is the same as you would for any batch script

```
set file=Ayylmao.txt
set Search_criteria=hello
set Replace_criteria=xello
powershell -command "(get-content %file%) -replace '%Search_criteria%','%Replace_criteria%' | set-content %file%"
```